# Are "help me get this open source tool to compile" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

As usual, it would be good to have an example, so here you go:

[Pfstools - compile for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408449/pfstools-compile-for-windows)

> I'm trying to get pfstools (as well as pfstmo and pfscalibration) working under Windows. These are basically an open source series of command line tools for High Dynamic Range (HDR) imaging.
>
> They were developed for Linux, so the documentation says that in Windows they need to be compiled and run in Cygwin, which is not a big deal except that I can't get them to compile following the instructions.
>
> Does anyone here have any experience using these in Windows? The project home page is here. Thanks.

I don't really think questions like these fit the normal mold of the standard close reasons. Every instinct I have says that the question is off topic, but I can't figure out why. He's not asking for a tool, it's clear what's being asked, there's probably only one answer, and it's clear a programmer would need to assist in the answer.

Perhaps it's already clear somewhere in a previous question or in the help center, but I have not been able to find it.

1. Are such questions on topic?
2. If no, what should the close reason be?

To be clear: **I think such questions should be closed**, I just want to know if I'm right and whether there's an appropriate close reason that isn't just a custom close reason.

The suggested duplicate is almost an exact duplicate, I agree, but that question doesn't doesn't talk about my point #2, e.g. what should the close reason be; either that needs to be addressed in the other question or this should remain open.

Comment: Maybe a close reason would be the lack of data about the error. How are we supposed to know what didn't work in his installation? Would a valid close reason be "unclear what you're asking"?

Comment: As written, "too broad" or more specifically the "debug" reason are applicable. "unclear" is probably a stretch...

Comment: Now, I could imagine less easily decided cases. And I think it's both possible to be on the right side of the line, and far far more likely to be on the wrong side. Which is where it gets uncomfortable...

Comment: 1.no.2.`recommend or find a book` and may be as Deduplicator says

Comment: Getting such stuff to compile/link is environment-sensitive.  More than anything else, it requires grunt-work.  Nobody wants to do that for free.

Comment: Questions about resolving a particular compiler or linker error, with a reasonably small example, seem just fine to me.  This question just doesn't provide enough information, and I've voted to close using the "debugging" reason.  (Note that the answer actually provides more information than the question!)

Comment: Given this, from the FAQ for pfstools, "What platforms does it work on?

pfstools is developed under Debian (sarge) on Intel based platform. It has also been successfully compiled under cygwin on Windows and Mac OS X (except pfsview, which requires qt).It should compile on any platform which is supported by automake/autoconf and which has required libraries (see dependencies in README file)" wouldn't it be best if the question could just be deleted? Seems @Ben was perhaps spot on (it's not clear if the parenthesised information appplies to Windows) but FAQ say, so why in SO?

Comment: @TinyGiant I can't think of anything more uniquely programming related than compiling code.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, in general such questions can be on-topic - they ask about problems with a compiler, which certainly is a [*software tool commonly used by programmers*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The question needs to include

- what compiler (version) was used, in what environment
- what code was compiled (for an open-source project a permalink *might* be enough)
- what command was used to execute the compiler (if a build tool is used, best include its config)
- what error occurred (complete message)

and if possible the offending part of the code.

Yes, the particular question fails to meet any of those requirements, and should be closed indeed. The appropriate close reason would be *off-topic* -> *MCVE missing* (that "*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include …*" one).

If the question is unlikely to be answered, maybe *off-topic* -> *problem that can no longer be reproduced and is unlikely to help future readers* could be used as well.

Comment: Yes, they CAN be on-topic as you have said, but usually they are not.  When asking for help on errors with code, we require that the asker be familiar with the code they are asking about and understand the purpose of each line of code, and that standard is hard to meet with third-party source.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't think that's strictly required. A problem with the compiler might not be a problem with the code. Especially as compiling seems to have worked for others.

Comment: @Bergi Too bad. It's still the responsibility of the person asking the question to reduce it to an MCVE. If the person asking the question can't, because that person is not familiar enough with the code base, the person should take the time to study the code base. If there are concrete small bits of code that are just too hard to understand, then that could make for another question that would be okay to ask on SO. (To be clear, the asker doesn't need to be familiar with the entire code base, just with the bits that aren't working, and just enough to reduce it to a decent question.)

Comment: @Bergi: I don't follow the stricter standard which is that users can only ask about their own code, period.

Answer (score -5):

No these questions are not appropriate unless the tools that the OP tries to install is a software tool commonly used by programmers.

That there is no specific close reason for installing other tools is probably just a space issue, you can only make boxes so large before they get unwieldy. If you look at the [super-user help](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) on what is on-topic there, you see you can ask about any computer software. So that would be a good alternative. If the software was on Unix & Linux, you could redirect them there as well.

Comment: ... and it's "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Never omit the fourth line, which is a limit on what the other three establish as scope.

Comment: I strongly disagree.  Compiling a program is a practical programming problem.  A compiler is a tool primarily used for programming.  These questions as a subject area are on topic.  It does not really matter what the user's ultimate goal is (modifying the code or just installing software that is only distributed by source code).  Of course, they do still have to stand up to the other quality requirements as well.